# Split ("extract") Columns using Panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a column called Country that can have a value of `USA, Canada, Japan`. For example:

```
Country
-------
Japan
Japan
USA
....
Canada
```

I want to split ("extract") the values into three individual columns (`Country_USA`, `Country_Canada`, and `Country_Japan`), and basically, a column will have a value of `1` if it matches the original value from the Country column. For example:

```
Country        -->    Country_Japan    Country_USA    Country_Canada
-------               -------------    -----------    ---------------
Japan                        1              0                0
USA                          0              1                0
Japan                        1              0                0
....
```

Is there a simple (non-tedious) way to do this using Panda / Python 3.x? Thanks!

Comment: Look at using `pd.get_dummies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and with [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html#pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix):

```
print(df.join(df['Country'].str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Country_')))
```

**Demo:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Japan','USA','Japan','Canada']})
print(df.join(df['Country'].str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Country_')))
```

Output:

```
  Country  Country_Canada  Country_Japan  Country_USA
0   Japan               0              1            0
1     USA               0              0            1
2   Japan               0              1            0
3  Canada               1              0            0
```

**Better version, thanks to Scott:**

```
print(df.join(pd.get_dummies(df)))
```

Output:

```
  Country  Country_Canada  Country_Japan  Country_USA
0   Japan               0              1            0
1     USA               0              0            1
2   Japan               0              1            0
3  Canada               1              0            0
```

**Another good version from Scott:**

```
print(df.assign(**pd.get_dummies(df)))
```

Output:

```
  Country  Country_Canada  Country_Japan  Country_USA
0   Japan               0              1            0
1     USA               0              0            1
2   Japan               0              1            0
3  Canada               1              0            0
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking..  +1

Comment: `print(df.join(pd.get_dummies(df)))`

Comment: @ScottBoston Oh wow!!!, i'll edit

Comment: Here's another trick using dictionary unpacking... `print(df.assign(**pd.get_dummies(df)))`

Comment: @ScottBoston Wow... You're expertise on pandas!!!

Comment: @ScottBoston, you are really a GURU for pandas, hats off sir.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes he is, based on this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrRE8.png

Comment: Works! Thanks to all who contributed :)

Comment: @ThomasWest Happy to help, :-O), 